Support paging keyboard shortcuts in Staging Ground
Please add support for keyboard shortcuts next page, previous page, first page, and last page shortcuts in the /staging-ground item listing webpage


pn (Page -> Next Page) + pp (Page -> Previous Page (for P>1)) work indeed on 'Main' + 'Meta', but how do you trigger a 'First Page' + 'Last Page'...? I can't find how to trigger those actions...? (I tried pf / pl / p0 / p3 / p [Shift/Ctrl] Right/Left-Arrow but none works... (FF130 on Win10)) // You could maybe also include j (Next Question) + k (Previous Question) in this 'Feature-Request', as those 2 Shortcuts are also not supported in the Staging Ground.

@chivracq the HTML is "broken" for first/last, therefore the shortcuts don't show up. For "First" the title of the first page is wrong "Go to page 1" (current) instead of "go to page 1" (expected). For the last page, the class "current" is missing, instead there is an "is-selected" class applied on the current page.

Ah..., alright, Thanks @VLAZ // And hum, this current Question would be a bit clearer anyway if the respective Shortcuts could be mentioned for all 4 actions...

@VLAZ hit the nail on the head.  Apparently the First/Last markup has been broken for about 4 years when we did some front end fixes/styling.  SG just needs to add a class of .pager to be included in the page keyboard shortcuts, so that should be pretty doable, but gimme the standard 6-8 wks to get it into and out of the queue

@chivracq, it's normally pf (page first) and pl (page last) if they work, but if they're wired up, they'll show in the help menu when you hit p.  So if you don't see them there, no combo will work.  Also, you can get the full help menu by typing ?

As a temporary1 fix, I created a userscript which fixes the keyboard navigation in lists for all lists2.
On StackApps: https://stackapps.com/q/10626
For Staging Ground it enables navigating to pages, as well as traversing the list of posts with U / J / K
Also, the installation section reproduced here for ease of access:

Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
(For instructions how to install userscripts: see the tag wiki here)
Code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Keyboard navigation fixes
// @description     Fix keyboard navigation shortcuts on most places to allow navigating to pages and going up/down the list.
// @author          VLAZ
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://superuser.com/*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/*
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @run-at          document-end
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @grant           GM.addStyle
// @version         1.0.0
// ==/UserScript==

/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
  ;// ./src/fixes.js
  /** appease all userscript managers */
  const addStyle = (...args) => /* eslint-disable-next-line new-cap */
      GM?.addStyle(...args) ?? GM_addStyle(...args);

  /** make previous/next shortcuts work */
  const fixPager = config => pager =>
      pager.classList.add(...config.pagerClassесToAdd);

  /** make "go to first page" work */
  const fixFirstPage = config => pager => {
      const firstPageButton = config.findFirstPage(pager);

      firstPageButton?.setAttribute("title", config.titleForFirstPage);
  };

  /** make "go to last page" work */
  const fixLastPage = config => pager => {
      const currentPage = config.findCurrentPage(pager);

      currentPage?.classList.add("current");
  };

  function fixAllPagers(config) {
      config.findPagers().forEach(fixPager(config));
  }

  function fixAllFirstPages(config) {
      config.findPagers().forEach(fixFirstPage(config));
  }

  function fixAllLastPages(config) {
      config.findPagers().forEach(fixLastPage(config));
  }

  function reInitiKeybindings() {
  //$.cache is missing some times which stops the destroy() call
      $.cache ??= {};
      $.cache[document[jQuery.expando]] ??= {};
      $.cache[document[jQuery.expando]].events = {};

      //turn it off and on again
      StackExchange.keyboardShortcuts.destroy();
      StackExchange.keyboardShortcuts.init();
  }

  /** make the keyboard selection highlight more visible in dark mode */
  function fixHighlightInDarkmode() {
      addStyle("body.theme-dark .keyboard-selected { box-shadow: 15px 15px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) inset; }");
  }

  ;// ./src/pagePredicates.js
  /** new answers to old questions tool*/
  const isNATO = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().contains("/new-answers-old-questions");

  const isProtectedQuestions = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().contains("/protected-questions");

  const isSuggestedEdit10kTool = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().startsWith("tools/suggested-edits");

  /** questions page, custom filters, tag main page, tag search*/
  const isQuestions = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().startsWith("/questions");

  /** regular search page */
  const isSearch = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().startsWith("/search");

  const isAllUsers = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase() === "/users"
          || url.pathname.toLowerCase() === "/users/";

  const isDiscussions = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().contains("/discussions");

  const isStagingGround = url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().startsWith("/staging-ground");


  const userPage = page => url =>
      url.pathname.toLowerCase().startsWith("/users/")
          && url.searchParams.get("tab")?.toLowerCase() === page;

  const isUserAnswers = userPage("answers");
  const isUserQuestions = userPage("questions");
  const isUserActivity = userPage("activity");


  ;// ./src/lookups.js
  function findPagers() {
      return document.querySelectorAll(".s-pagination");
  }

  function findFirstPage(pager) {
      const pages = pager.querySelectorAll("a[href]");

      return [].find.call(pages, el => {
          const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(el.search);

          const isPage1 = searchParams.get("page") === "1"
              || searchParams.get("pg") === "1";

          const noPage = !searchParams.has("page")
              && !searchParams.has("pg");

          return isPage1 || noPage;
      });
  }

  function findCurrentPage(pager) {
      return pager.querySelector(".is-selected");
  }

  ;// ./src/config.js


  const ALL_CLASSES_FOR_PAGER = ["pager-questions", "pager-answers", "pager"];
  const TITLE_FOR_FIRST_PAGE = "go to page 1";
  const NO_CLASSES = [];

  /** { predicate: Predicate, pagerClassесToAdd: string[], selectionFix: () => void } */
  const PAGE_SPECIFIC_CONFIG = [
      {
          title: "10k tools - NATO",
          predicate: isNATO,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager-answers"],
      },
      {
          title: "10k tools - suggested edits stats",
          predicate: isSuggestedEdit10kTool,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager"],
      },
      {
          title: "10k tools - protected questions",
          predicate: isProtectedQuestions,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager"],
      },
      {
          title: "/questions",
          predicate: isQuestions,
          pagerClassесToAdd: NO_CLASSES,
      },
      {
          title: "search pages",
          predicate: isSearch,
          pagerClassесToAdd: NO_CLASSES,
      },
      {
          title: "/users",
          predicate: isAllUsers,
          pagerClassесToAdd: NO_CLASSES,
      },
      {
          title: "User profile - activity page",
          predicate: isUserActivity,
          pagerClassесToAdd: NO_CLASSES,
      },
      {
          title: "User profile - answers",
          predicate: isUserAnswers,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager-answers"],
      },
      {
          title: "User profile - questions",
          predicate: isUserQuestions,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager-answers"],
      },
      {
          title: "Discussions",
          predicate: isDiscussions,
          pagerClassесToAdd: NO_CLASSES,
          selectionFix: () => {
              document.querySelector(".s-post-summary")
                  .parentElement
                  .setAttribute("id", "questions");
          }
      },
      {
          title: "Staging ground",
          predicate: isStagingGround,
          pagerClassесToAdd: ["pager"],
          selectionFix: () => {
              document.querySelector(".js-listing-table-container")
                  .setAttribute("id", "questions");
          },
      }
  ];

  /** set up script to run on the current page - select correct config */
  function init() {
      const url = new URL(location);

      const config = PAGE_SPECIFIC_CONFIG
          .find(({predicate}) => predicate(url)) ?? {};

      //attach common config
      config.pagerClassесToAdd ??= ALL_CLASSES_FOR_PAGER;
      Object.assign(config, {
          titleForFirstPage: TITLE_FOR_FIRST_PAGE,
          findPagers: findPagers,
          findFirstPage: findFirstPage,
          findCurrentPage: findCurrentPage,
      });

      return config;
  }

  ;// ./src/index.js


  function main(config) {
      fixAllPagers(config);
      fixAllFirstPages(config);
      fixAllLastPages(config);
      fixHighlightInDarkmode(config);

      if (config.selectionFix) {
          config.selectionFix();
          reInitiKeybindings(config);
      }
  }

  const CONFIG = init();
  main(CONFIG);
/******/ })();



1 just for 6-8 weeks 
2 see list of known issues for where it does not currently work

Thanks for the report. Pager keyboard shortcuts should work on the staging ground list view now:

P + P - Previous
P + N - Next


what about first and last?

Yeah..., that's a good start, but "status-completed" sounds a bit "premature" to me...!: pf & pl are missing indeed, only pp & pn work, and also only on the 'Proposed questions' Tab, nothing works/is implemented for the 'Review h/History' Tab... ("h/History", choose your spelling,  just another "Inconsistent Capitalization glitch")... // And u/j/k are also still missing btw...
